# Wordpress Divi Blog module - no option to control number of posts

Tags: wordpress, limit, blogs, divi

According to this page here: https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/blog/

I should have the option within the divi blog module settings to control the number of posts displayed i.e.

Posts Number: 6

Now, on the site in question, the number of posts IS set to 6 (because we have more than 6 posts in this category, but only 6 are displaying) BUT the option to change this number is not presented when editing the blog module.

Does anyone know why?  and more importantly where/how I can override the limit to change the number of posts displayed?

Thanks!

Comment: So you don't have the option called 'Post Count' within your blog module? If that's the case then have you contacted Elegant Themes support? If the default functionality of the blog module isn't there for you, it's either a conflict with a plugin or an issue with the theme. You could check your 'System Status' under the Divi -> Support Center area in your admin. ET support is the best first place to go though if you're not comfortable with debugging yourself. (ps. I know this is an old post, but thought this would be useful for anyone experiencing something similar)

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked it, on my sites it's possible. Blog / content options / post number. And with 'post offset number' you can change the offset :-)

When it doesn't work (DIVI is full of bugs with Elegant Themes will not fix), have you tried to add another Blog-Module on your site and test it there? I had several times the error that i can't do something in a module, but when I add the same module again then it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

You have the Blog module override process for Divi 4+ here (I just test it and it's working fine) :
[Moving Blog module in Child theme](https://help.elegantthemes.com/en/articles/4532734-moving-blog-module-in-child-theme)

Comment: Downvoted - Interesting article, but it doesn't help the OP and it doesn't address their question at all.

Comment: I had the same problem than freestate and I finally succeed in overiding this module like described in the article.

Comment: I appreciate it probably 'fixed' or 'patched' whatever issue you were experiencing, but it doesn't address the actual problem/issue. If the standard/default Divi blog module isn't working, it would be a much better idea to figure out why and fix it rather than, effectively, messing around adding custom code, ignoring the actual issue and claiming it's a 'fix'.